# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'appController' bean method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Good morning all, i'm dealing with an Ambiguous mapping i cannot decode...
I'm using Spring mvc 4.0.6 and hibernate 4.3.6
I'm getting this error while launching the war in tomcat:

```
ERROR [localhost-startStop-2]: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'appController' bean method 
public java.lang.String it.besmart.controller.AppController.newClient(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
to {[//new],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'appController' bean method
public java.lang.String it.besmart.controller.AppController.saveClient(it.besmart.models.Client,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap) mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1768)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'appController' bean method 
public java.lang.String it.besmart.controller.AppController.newClient(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
to {[//new],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'appController' bean method
public java.lang.String it.besmart.controller.AppController.saveClient(it.besmart.models.Client,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap) mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 25 more
```

I can't understand why i'm getting this error. AppController is quite straight

```
package it.besmart.controller;
import it.besmart.models.Client;
import it.besmart.service.ClientService;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    ClientService clientService;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/list" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listClients(ModelMap model){
        List<Client> clients = clientService.findAllClients();
        model.addAttribute("clients", clients);
        return "allclients";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/new"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String newClient(ModelMap model){
        Client client = new Client();
        model.addAttribute("client", client);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        return "registration";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/new"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveClient(@Valid Client client, BindingResult result, ModelMap model){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "registration";
        }


        clientService.saveClient(client);
        model.addAttribute("success", "Client" + client.getNomeClient() + "registrato correttamente");

        return "success";

    }


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-{name}-client"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateClient(@Valid Client client, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, @PathVariable String name ){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "registration";
        }

        if(!clientService.isClientNameUnique(client.getIdClient(), client.getNomeClient())){
            FieldError idErr = new FieldError("client", "name", messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.nome_client", new String[]{client.getNomeClient()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            result.addError(idErr);
            return "registration";
        }
        clientService.saveClient(client);
        model.addAttribute("success", "Client" + client.getNomeClient() + "aggiornato correttamente");

        return "success";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/delete-{id}-client" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String deleteClient(@PathVariable int id){
        clientService.deleteClientById(id);
        return "redirect:/list";
    }


    }
```

ClientService.java

```
package it.besmart.service;

import it.besmart.models.Client;

import java.util.List;

public interface ClientService {

    Client findById(int id);

    void saveClient(Client client);

    void updateClient(Client client);

    void deleteClientById(int id);

    List <Client> findAllClients();

    Client findClientByName(String name);

    boolean isClientNameUnique(Integer id, String name);

}
```

It looks to me like it's quite straight everything... I'm quite new to this kind of application..
Thanks

Comment: There is the @RequestMapping("/") at top of controller and then the same url value "/" in listClients method. Can you remove the topmost controller-level @RequestMapping("/") and try again to see if the error goes away?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This is the error message you are getting:

> Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'appController' bean method 
>   public java.lang.String it.besmart.controller.AppController.newClient(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
>   to {[//new],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'appController' bean method public java.lang.String it.besmart.controller.AppController.saveClient(it.besmart.models.Client,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap) mapped.

It's telling you you're mapping more than one method to handle a `POST` to the URL `/new`.  If the web browser makes a `POST` request to the URL `/new`, which of your methods should handle it?

Here are the two offending methods:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/new"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String newClient(ModelMap model){
        Client client = new Client();
        model.addAttribute("client", client);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        return "registration";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/new"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveClient(@Valid Client client, BindingResult result, ModelMap model){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "registration";
        }


        clientService.saveClient(client);
        model.addAttribute("success", "Client" + client.getNomeClient() + "registrato correttamente");

        return "success";

    }
```

I suspect that the first of these is incorrect; you probably want to use `RequestMethod.GET` instead of `RequestMethod.POST` for that.

Comment: [java-lang-illegalstateexception-ambiguous-mapping-cannot-map-controller-method/](https://javatute.com/spring-boot/java-lang-illegalstateexception-ambiguous-mapping-cannot-map-controller-method/) similar. For my case, I have `@RestController` and I have map `/webhook` and method `webHook()`. I have to change the method name `webHook()` to another name. And the `Ambiguous` error disappears.

Answer (score 9):

I encountered this and solved it by replacing `name` with `value` in `PostMapping`. Request Handler was

```
@PostMapping(name = "/greetings/sayHi")
public Object sayHi() {

  return "Hello";
}
```

Replacing key `name`

```
@PostMapping(value = "/greetings/sayHi")
public Object sayHi() {
    
  return "Hello";
}
```

Comment: Great! This is easy to miss it and get irritated. if endpoints are mapped with PostMapping, GetMapping, you could also remove the value or name property and just pass the endpoint as a string only. like this
@PostMapping("/greetings/sayHi")

Answer (score 5):

In my case I couldn't find one of the methods in the error. The server wasn't being updated. Try clean and rebuild. If using intellij delete the [project dir]/target folder.

Answer (score 2):

Also had same error when Tomcat's `Tomcat 8.0\work\Catalina\localhost\` not being cleared properly. Had to delete by hand, restart Tomcat, then app run with no errors.

Answer (score 2):

in my case one of the upper classes was already defined the mapping request. that's why it was giving me error.

Answer (score 1):

Add params to the following code and you are good to go.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/new"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "filter")
public String saveClient(@PathVariable("filter") final String filter,@Valid Client client, BindingResult result, ModelMap model){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "registration";
    }


    clientService.saveClient(client);
    model.addAttribute("success", "Client" + client.getNomeClient() + "registrato correttamente");

    return "success";

}
```

- Remember to supply params to your url eg https://localhost/url?filter=filterBy OR http://localhost/url/filter
  based on your url configuration change the controller method accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It is unrelated to the issue reported here, butsince this is the top most search in google on this issue. I wanted to also mention another reason this issue occurs is when you mark your controller method as private (It happens to me because I use IDE auto-complete for methods).

```
@RequestMapping(value="/products",  method=RequestMethod.POST)
private List<Product> getProducts() {
    return productService.getProducts();
}
```

Making it public should resolve the issue.

Comment: `name="/products"`? Shouldn't it be `value="/products"`?

Comment: Thank you. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/new"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String newClient(ModelMap model)

@RequestMapping(value = {"/new"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveClient(@Valid Client client, BindingResult result, ModelMap)
```

Try generalizing this part. Maybe values being the same are causing ambiguity for request mapping.

Answer (score 0):

*Remark: This solution applies to the error message but not to the question itself.*

In my case the bean definitions lacks an id which leads to duplicate instantiation:

```
<bean class="it.besmart.controller.AppController"/>
```

My solution was to add the id:

```
<bean id="appController" class="it.besmart.controller.AppController"/>
```