# Spring Batch Admin inside Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am trying to integrate spring batch admin into an existing spring boot application. (includes spring batch and swagger)

The application is Java configured.

I have one

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

public final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
public final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
public final VehicleSalesObjectRepository vehicleSalesObjectRepository;
private JobRepository jobRepository;

@Value("${storage.importFile}")
private Resource importFile;

@Autowired
public BatchConfig(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
        VehicleSalesObjectRepository vehicleSalesObjectRepository, JobRepository jobRepository) {
    this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
    this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
    this.vehicleSalesObjectRepository = vehicleSalesObjectRepository;
    this.jobRepository = jobRepository;
}
....
```

that configures my job.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@ImportResource({ "classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/servlet-config.xml",
        "classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/webapp-config.xml" })
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {....}
```

When starting the server I always get the following exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfig' defined in file [BatchConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'jobBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ba801bb9 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:22)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'jobBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ba801bb9 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'jobBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ba801bb9 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ba801bb9 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42e0f38d.jobRepository(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.jobBuilders(AbstractBatchConfiguration.java:58)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42e0f38d.CGLIB$jobBuilders$7(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42e0f38d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9277f7da.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42e0f38d.jobBuilders(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Any hints?
What is the preferred way to integrate Spring Batch Admin into an existing Spring Boot Application?

When running my spring boot application and the codecentric batch admin as separate applications everything works fine. But I want it integrated. ;)

Thanks for you help!
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Two things that I can see,

Spring Batch Admin already defines `JobRepository` in `execution-context.xml` so I think , you should try `@Autowired` for that bean in your application usage.

Secondly, you should remove `@EnableBatchProcessing` from your configuration class and put `@EnableBatchAdmin` on your main class - `MyApplication`

Refer [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573583/spring-batch-admin-spring-boot-ambiguous-mapping-cannot-map-org-springfram) too in case you see any of those errors.