# Configuring Spring batch Admin UI

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I need to create spring batch Job using annotations and integrate spring batch admin UI for the same. I would like to connect to a MySql database instance so that spring batch connects to the database. Spring Batch Admin UI should also point to the database and should populate the data accordingly. Kindly provide a sample project for the same. I referred websites as much as can and end up with getting confused

Comment: The Spring Batch Admin UI is being decommissioned at the end of this year.  I'd recommend using Spring Cloud Data Flow for future development.

Comment: You haven't mentioned if you are running Spring Batch with Boot or without Boot. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573583/spring-batch-admin-spring-boot-ambiguous-mapping-cannot-map-org-springfram) are questions and answer by me for my attempts for similar task which might be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I went with spring cloud data flow. It's really cool and efficient. But I am facing one issue in that, my spring batch application was running on embedded tomcat before. If I integrate Spring cloud task with my existing application and annotate my main class with @EnableTask my application is not getting hosted am getting

Comment: Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@16a0ee18: startup date [Thu Jan 04 23:41:33 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy error. Am struck with the issue. can we do that. or should we do as a war? Iam using Spring Boot